# Which takes more work to render the desktop: Windows or Ubuntu?

Tags: unity, windows

Question say it all really. The backstory is I have an older laptop with 4Gb and a dual core Intel Celeron clocked at 2.2Ghz. Absolutely everything on Ubuntu is slow for me, heck even navigating firefox is a complete chore.

I read once that Unity may be eating up significantly more of my CPU for rendering, leaving less resources for using applications. How true is this? How much worse would it be on Windows?

Comment: Your CPU has onboard GPU that does rendering. I think. Both Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows Vista 64 bit would perform well I think.

Comment: In goggle chrome you sometimes have to tell it to use hardware acceleration but I don't know about Fire Fox.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Eh.. if OP has a low-power Celeron WinVista is *definitely* not the way to go.

Comment: @patrick I have similar with T5750 processor. He didn't give his model #. Mine runs Ubuntu 14.04 and Vista very nicely last time I used it. Watch YouTube and 7 chrome tabs with hardware acceleration barely hit 50% CPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did some performance tests. On my laptop with an i5-6200u Windows Explorer (explorer.exe) on Windows 10, which is roughly equivalent to a Windows Desktop environment, uses about 0-1% CPU idle, and will quickly spike to about 5-7% when opening multiple windows, folders, etc.

Unity 7, on the other hand, is roughly the same in terms of resources. It uses 0-1% idle, and sometimes spikes to 5-6%, but quickly settles down (when manipulating desktops, windows, etc.).

Unity 8, which isn't optimized well at all yet, easily uses up to 10%.

Just to add in an oddball, in i3 wm, the entire window manager (search, desktops, etc.), uses ~.6% **max**.

What I can say certainly is that you shouldn't be using heavy DE's such as Unity on hardware such as yours. I highly recommend **XFCE** or **LXDE**, which are very light desktop environments.

Even more, the CPU/GPU may not even be the issue. Try clearing up some unused packages, or even performing a clean reinstall. The difference in performance may be massive.